# mmenu wordpress plugin title does not change and error message

Tags: mmenu

I am using the mmenu Plugin on a wordpress Site, it works great and looks good, but if i click on a parent to open a sub menu the Title does not change.

also i have 2 errors in the console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`

the errors both occur when he trys to use "this.node.menu.id"

`const e = a(this.opts.backButton, q) , t = "#" + this.node.menu.id;`

Anybody had the same issue?

[image]

i tried to change the Settings but it didnt help.